# how to change the Hover font family in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[how can i change the Hover font family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBXqh.png)
VSCode Version: 1.56.2
OS Version: Windows 10

I want to change the Hover font family of vscode,what should i do?

Comment: There are two fonts when you hover, which one do you want to change?

Comment: ![image.png](https://i.loli.net/2021/06/10/TvW1DGjby7EBUqL.png) thanks for your reply! Just as this screenshot, I want to change the font  circled in red box, It's been bothering me for a long time

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported yet. The hover uses the `system-ui` font family and sets the same `fontSize` as defined for the editor.

ref: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/163093#issuecomment-1276730454